# How do I fix this constraint programmatically in iOS 13.X?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I wanted to add a horizontal stack view to my application so I can have a scoring mechanism for an image.

I created a private method in the `StackView` class that would generate a `UIButton` with dimensions of 44x44 within my stack view but it seems that the `UIButton` fills in the entirety of the stack view instead.

I made sure to programmatically create constraints for the `UIButton` within my private method, and tried adjusting the constraints within the storyboard pane, but to no avail. I have attached images of what I'm referring to below.

[image: code]

[image: storyboard]

[image: simulator result]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the constraints you set for your `UIButton` make it unable to satisfy conflicting constraints.

Xcode specifies conflicting constraints under this piece of code in Debugger:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
```

A possible workaround is to add your `UIButton` into a `UIView`:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = .red
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    
let viewButton = UIView()
viewButton.addSubview(button)
    
stack.addArrangedSubview(viewButton)
```

This would result in something like this (*for this example I've set `viewButton.backgroundColor` to gray*):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNC4.png)

Comment: Huzzah! I used the workaround you suggested and was able to get my cute little square to show up properly within the UIStackView. Thanks a million, @heitor!